# Display suite PHP field using tokens

Tags: display-suite

I'm trying to use a [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) field to wrap an image in a div.

What I also want to do is to htmlspecialchars on the token [node:field_mainimage].

It doesn't want to work for me. Is there any other way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Where are those images placed ?

If this is in content type, you can style the content type content by using custom tpl.php files and wrap your images in div there. (in sites/all/thems/yourtheme , that is.)

Also, you can create template files even for fields.

That gives you enormous power of controlling output :) .

It is bit "dirty", but you can also wrap images in div using jQuery. But first method is cleaner.

Comment: Well, the wrapping isn't the problem. The problem is that the htmlspecialchars don't do anything. It seems like it tries to work on the [node:field_mainimage] and not on it's value.

Comment: If you have nerve to translate your logic from tokens to template files, there you have greater control. If not, some token-experienced user will possibly answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want wrap image field formatter (html output of field) in another div (or other html containers) I recommend to use [Field Group module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group).

It allows you in formatters configuration (admin/structure/types/manage/*/display) to group any fields and configure to wrap them by basic HTML wrappers, tabs, multistep form etc.